# Task lintVital crash with AS 3.0 Beta 1

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, lint, android-studio-3.0

Since I updated to Android Studio 3.0 Beta 1, the task `lintVital` crash with `java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)` when I generate signed APK.
All works great with Android Studio 3.0 Canary 9

I already try to:

- clean build
- restart and invalidate
- delete all files of Gradle (`~/.gradle` and `PROJECT/.gradle`)

Log with `--stacktrace --debug`:

```
11:17:58.416 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
11:17:58.416 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
11:17:58.416 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
11:17:58.416 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
11:17:58.416 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalBeta'.
11:17:58.416 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
11:17:58.416 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
11:17:58.416 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
11:17:58.416 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalBeta'.
11:17:58.416 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
11:17:58.416 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
11:17:58.416 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
11:17:58.416 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
11:17:58.416 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
11:17:58.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
11:17:58.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
11:17:58.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
11:17:58.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
11:17:58.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
11:17:58.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
11:17:58.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
11:17:58.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
11:17:58.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
11:17:58.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
11:17:58.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
11:17:58.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
11:17:58.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
11:17:58.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
11:17:58.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
11:17:58.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
11:17:58.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
11:17:58.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
11:17:58.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
11:17:58.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
11:17:58.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
11:17:58.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
11:17:58.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
11:17:58.418 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11:17:58.418 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
11:17:58.418 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
11:17:58.418 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
11:17:58.418 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
11:17:58.418 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 14s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: This bug is fixed with **Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2**

---

One workaround that I found (but it's temporary...). In `gradle.build` file:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        lintOptions {
            ...
            // Caution!! This will disable lint vital lint check...
            checkReleaseBuilds false
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error too. I'm at AS 3.0 Beta2 too, though. :(

Comment: Yes. :app:lintVitalBeta FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalBeta'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 46s

Comment: It occurs on both Gnu/Linux and OSX.

Comment: I'm still facing this problem with Android Studio 3.0.1 :(